# Assigning console.log to another object (Webkit issue)

Tags: javascript, logging, console, webkit, firebug

I wanted to keep my logging statements as short as possible while preventing console from being accessed when it doesn't exist; I came up with the following solution:

```
var _ = {};
if (console) {
    _.log = console.debug;
} else {
    _.log = function() { }
}
```

To me, this seems quite elegant, and it works great in Firefox 3.6 (including preserving the line numbers that make `console.debug` more useful than `console.log`). But it doesn't work in Safari 4. [Update: Or in Chrome. So the issue seems to be a difference between Firebug and the Webkit console.] If I follow the above with

```
console.debug('A')
_.log('B');
```

the first statement works fine in both browsers, but the second generates a "TypeError: Type Error" in Safari. Is this just a difference between how Firebug and the Safari Web Developer Tools implement console? If so, it is VERY annoying on <strike>Apple's</strike> Webkit's part. Binding the console function to a prototype and then instantiating, rather than binding it directly to the object, doesn't help.

I could, of course, just call `console.debug` from an anonymous function assigned to `_.log`, but then I'd lose my line numbers. Any other ideas?

Comment: It's a feature of webkit, not a bug ;-) https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20141

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146316/why-does-scope-reduction-in-safari-break-existing-code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, if `console` is indeed undefined (as it is in browsers such as IE), you'll get an error. You should check it instead as a property of the global object, which is `window` in browsers. It's also a good idea in general to test a feature before using it, so I've added a test for the `debug` method.

Possibly the implementation of `console.debug` in Safari relies on its value of `this` being a reference to `console`, which will not be the case if you call it using `_.log` (`this` will instead be a reference to `_`). Having done a quick test, this does seem to be the case and the following fixes the problem:

```
var _ = {};
if (typeof window.console != "undefined"
       && typeof window.console.debug == "function") {
    _.log = function() {
        window.console.debug.apply(window.console, arguments);
    }
} else {
    _.log = function() { }
}
```

Comment: Right, that's the conventional approach, but it has a serious flaw: it loses the line numbers. If you call _.log() from anywhere in the app, the console will report that output as being generated from within the _.log() function, not the original source. So the benefit of using console.debug() instead of console.log() is lost.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be easier just to stick to using `console` without any alias or wrapper, and just define it with stub methods if it doesn't exist? For example: `if (typeof window.console != "undefined") { window.console = { debug: function() {} } }` etc.

Comment: I think you're right, Tim (though you mean `typeof window.console == "undefined"` rather than `!=`, right?). I should perhaps abandon my quest for brevity in favor of just assigning a dummy console as needed.

Comment: Oops. Yes, I did mean `==` rather than `!=`.

Comment: This also fails in IE because console.debug does not have an apply method.. Who woulda thunk ?

Comment: @HaxElit: Indeed: `console` is a host object and methods of host objects in IE prior to version 9 never inherited from `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a solution to this myself (this is how I found your question).

As Tim pointed out, webkit browsers (Safari, Chrome) rely on `this` being `console` in this case. Firefox, however, does not. So in FF you can reassign the function and preserve the line numbers (otherwise all logs look like they originated in the logging function, which is not very useful). The best way to check which browser you are is to do it and check the result. Here is how to check it (in Coffeescript):

```
# Check to see if reassigning of functions work
f = console.log
assignSupported = true
try
  f('Initializing logging...')
catch e
  assignSupported = false
```

Later, when you make the functions check assignSupported and act accordingly:

```
levels =
  ERROR: 1
  WARN:  2
  LOG:   3
  INFO:  4
  DEBUG: 6

log.setLevel = (newLevel) ->
  for label, level of levels
    if level > newLevel # Skip low levels
      continue

    name = label.toLowerCase()
    f = -> # Fallback - empty function. In Js: var f = function () {}
    if console?[name]
      if assignSupported
        f = console[name] # Wee, we'll have line numbers.
      else
        # Webkit need the this of console.log (namely, console)
        # preserved, so we use a wrapper.
        #
        # Calling console[name] within the returned wrapper
        # makes [name] a subject of the closure, meaning
        # that it's the last value in the iteration -
        # we need to preserve it.
        f = ((n) ->
          return (-> console[n].apply(console, arguments)))(name)
    log[name] = f

log.setLevel levels.DEBUG
```

The lines:

```
f = ((n) ->
  return (-> console[n].apply(console, arguments)))(name)
```

might look a bit odd. This is because `name` is the loop variable and is lexically bound, meaning that the value at the time of execution will be used, which will always be the last `level`. It compiles to this javascript (in case it's easier to read):

```
f = (function(n) {
  return (function() {
    return console[n].apply(console, arguments);
  });
})(name);
```