# Why does scope reduction in Safari break existing code?

Tags: javascript, safari

Firefox has no problem with

```
var logger = window.console.log,  // breaks Safari but not Firefox
```

but Safari gives a Type Error the first place I try to use `logger()`.  Note the snippet below.

I went ahead and replaced all my logger()'s with window.console.log() to get rid of the error.

I don't understand why Safari doesn't like it and why it calls it a type error.

**Error**

TypeError: Type error

**Snippet**

```
/*log
**
**
**
*/
NS.log = function (arg) {
    if (window.console) {
        var logger = window.console.log,  // breaks Safari but not Firefox
            str1 = Object.prototype.toString.call(arg);
// ... snip
```

Comment: My first guess would be that it's because the `this` inside `logger` is no longer `console` (instead it's `window`) and Safari doesn't like it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619187/assigning-console-log-to-another-object-webkit-issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var logger = window.console.log.bind(window.console)
```